# Arithmetic version of "Attaching maps" for moduli of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces

I am looking for a reference for attaching maps of moduli of curves with marked points. Especially I would like to know whether they descend over $\mathbb{Z}$. On one hand this seems very hard to believe since the topological nature of the construction, but on the other hand the moduli spaces are defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ so I decided to ask here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean the maps $\overline M_{g,n+1} \times \overline M_{g',n'+1} \to \overline M_{g+g',n+n'}$, etc.? Sure, those are all defined over $\mathbb Z$. The original reference for all these things is Knudsen's "Projectivity of the moduli space of stable curves II".

Comment: Another reference for Knudsen clutching in Section 2.2 of https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gerard.freixas/Site/Recherche_files/SingARR_arxiv.pdf